# Need a batch file or a shell file that will take the current calendar month, and make directories for each day.

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

this is my first time posting on here, so I apologize if I do something wrong. 
I need a batch file or a shell file that I can run at the beginning of the month to make directories with folder names in the following format YYYYMMDD for every day of that month. So essentially I will have a folder called (Let's use an example here and just say reports.
Inside the reports folder I need folders 20140901 20140902 all through the calendar month.

So far I have this code:

```
echo var D = new Date() > tmp.js 
echo D = (D.getFullYear()*100+D.getMonth()+1)*100+D.getDate() >> tmp.js 
echo WScript.Echo( 'set YYYYMMDD='+D ) >> tmp.js 
echo @echo off > tmp.bat 
cscript //nologo tmp.js >> tmp.bat 
call tmp.bat
mkdir %YYYYMMDD%
```

I get that you can make a folder based on the local date as well, however I am not sure the logic required to tell it to "skip ahead until 10/1/2014.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=./- " %%a IN ("%date%") DO (
 CALL :SETsz yy %%c
 CALL :SETsz mm %%b
)
IF %yy% lss 2000 SET /a yy+=2000
SET cdate=31
FOR %%a IN (2 2 2 4 6 9 11) DO IF %%a==%mm% SET /a cdate-=1
SET /a cdate=((%yy%*100)+%mm%)*100+%cdate%
SET /a yy=%yy% %% 4
IF %yy%%mm%==02 SET /a cdate+=1
FOR /L %%a IN (1%cdate:~-2%,-1,101) DO ECHO(MD reports\!cdate!&SET /a cdate-=1

GOTO :EOF
:setsz
SET cdate=%2
IF %cdate:~0,1%==0 (SET %1=%cdate:~1%) ELSE (SET %1=%2)
GOTO :eof
```

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

This is made way more complex because you haven't told us which particular date format you use. It should work with any separator, but I used my format `dd/mm/yyyy` for testing. If you use suppressed-leading-zero or two-digit years, it should work as-is.

If you use a leading dayname, then `tokens` will need to be changed to `2-4` in place of `1-3`. The particular fields `%%b` and `%%c` used in the first `for` "loop" would need to be `%%a`, `%%b` or `%%c` depending on the sequence you use in your date format.

You can test the routine by using

```
set date=1/02/2012
```

(for example) in the line directly before the "FOR /f ..." line. Normally, I'd warn against attempting to change `date` as it's a "magic variable" established by the system and overriding it can cause chaos. In this case however, it follows a `setlocal` command, so the date-override inserted will be backed out when the routine ends; hence it's safe during testing.

Comment: This seems to work exactly like I need it to, however I did notice once issue. When I run your script it sets the year field as 2002 instead of 2014. We use the 9/2/2014 format here. Sorry I forgot to include that. Is this something that I need to add? This is what I've done to make the code correct, however I don't feel it is the proper fix.
    IF %yy% lss 2000 SET /a yy+=2012

Comment: I'd suggest that your date format is actually `Wed(nesday) 9/2/2014` meaning September 2nd, 2014. You would need to change `tokens` to `2-4` not `1-3` as I mentioned, and you'd need `:setsz mm %%a` in place of `:setsz mm %%b`.

Answer (score 0):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

The for loop will simply make 31 folders for that year and month when it is run.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

for /L %%a in (1,1,31) do if %%a LSS 10 (md %YYYY%%MM%0%%a) else (md %YYYY%%MM%%%a)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Magoo your answer worked. I really appreciate it.

Here is what I finally ended up using.

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /f "tokens=2-4delims=./- " %%a IN ("%date%") DO (
 CALL :SETsz yy %%c
 CALL :setsz mm %%a
)
IF %yy% lss 2000 SET /a yy+=2000
SET cdate=31
FOR %%a IN (2 2 2 4 6 9 11) DO IF %%a==%mm% SET /a cdate-=1
SET /a cdate=((%yy%*100)+%mm%)*100+%cdate%
SET /a yy=%yy% %% 4
IF %yy%%mm%==02 SET /a cdate+=1
FOR /L %%a IN (1%cdate:~-2%,-1,101) DO MD C:\Users\spoling\Desktop\!cdate!&SET /a cdate-=1

GOTO :EOF
:setsz
SET cdate=%2
IF %cdate:~0,1%==0 (SET %1=%cdate:~1%) ELSE (SET %1=%2)
GOTO :eof
```